# Negative binomial distribution mean and variance

Tags: distributions, self-study, negative-binomial-distribution

The equation below indicates expected value of negative binomial distribution. I need a derivation for this formula. I have searched a lot but can't find any solution. Thanks for helping :)

$
E(X)=\sum _{x=r}^{}x\times \left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r-1\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}=\frac{r}{p}
$

I have tried:
\begin{align}
E(X)&=\sum _{x=r}^{}x\times \left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r-1\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\&=\sum _{x=r}^{}x\times \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)!\times ((x-1-(r-1))!}\times {p}^{r}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&=\sum _{x=r}^{}\frac{x!}{(r-1)!\times ((x-r)!}\times {p}^{r}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&\Rightarrow \phantom{\rule{0ex}{0ex}}\sum _{x=r}^{}r\times \frac{x!}{r!\times (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&=\frac{r}{p}\times \sum _{x=r}^{}\frac{x!}{r!\times (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r+1}\times (1-p{)}^{x-r}
\end{align}

If the power of p in the last equation were not r + 1, I can implement Newton Binomial. So It will be true. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please add a self-study tag? And what have you already tried?

Comment: Yes I have tried.I updated my question and added self-study tag.

Comment: Hi, please align your equals signs in your derivation so it’s easy to read.

Comment: Derive the mgf (or the cgf or the cf or the pgf) and go on from there.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution to check your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to complement whuber's answer by a bit longer but purely arithmetical solution:

\begin{align}
E(X)&=\sum _{x=r}^{\infty}x \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r} (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&=\sum _{x=r}^{\infty}(x - r + r) \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r} (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&=\sum _{x=r}^{\infty}(x - r) \frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r}(1-p)^{x-r} + r \sum _{x=r}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! (x-r)!}\times {p}^{r} (1-p{)}^{x-r}\\
&=\sum _{x=r + 1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)!}{(r-1)! (x - r - 1)!}\times {p}^{r}(1-p)^{x-r} + r \sum _{x=r}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r-1\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r} (1-p)^{x-r}\\
&=\sum _{x=r + 1}^{\infty}\frac{r(1 - p)}{p}\frac{(x-1)!}{r! (x - r - 1)!}\times {p}^{r+1}(1-p)^{x-r-1} + r\\
&=\frac{r(1 - p)}{p}\sum _{x=r + 1}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r+1}(1-p)^{x-r-1} + r\\
&=\frac{r(1 - p)}{p} + r\\
& = \frac{r}{p}.
\end{align}

Here we twice used the fact that the sum of all of the probabilies of a discrete random variable is equal to one:

$$\sum _{x=r}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r-1\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r} (1-p)^{x-r} = \sum _{x=r}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = x)  = 1,$$

where $X$ is a negative binomial with parameters $r$ and $p$, and similarly

$$\sum _{x=r + 1}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}x-1\\ r\end{array}\right)\times {p}^{r+1}(1-p)^{x-r-1} = \sum _{x=r+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X^\prime = x)  = 1,$$

where $X^\prime$ is a negative binomial with parameters $r + 1$ and $p$.

**Note:** In all of the calculations above, I was using the notation given in the question. It is worth mentioning that there are at least two different ways to define a negative binomial distribution: either $X$ counts the number of failures, given $r$ successes (this is the most common definition), or $X$ counts the number of overall trials, given $r$ successes. The question implicitly assumes the second definition, whereas whuber's answer provides solution for the first one. Hence, the answers are different but are consistent with each other. In the first case, $E(X) = \frac{r(1-p)}{p}$ represents the average number of failures before $r$ successes, whereas in the second case $E(X) = \frac{r}{p}$ stands for the average number of trials with $r$ successes. Clearly, $$\frac{r(1-p)}{p} + r = \frac{r}{p}.$$

Comment: It would be good to know why your answer differs from mine.  It's likely a difference in parametrization conventions--but you should make that explicit.

Comment: @whuber You are right, I added the explanation of the differences to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Negative Binomial distribution with parameters $r\gt 0$ and $0\lt p\lt 1.$  [According to one definition,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) it has positive probabilities for all natural numbers $k\ge 0$ given by

$$\Pr(k\mid r, p) = \binom{-r}{k}(-1)^k (1-p)^r\,p^k.$$

**Newton's Binomial Theorem** states that when $|q|\lt 1$ and $x$ is any number,

$$(1+q)^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}{k} q^k.$$

Because this sum converges absolutely it can be differentiated term by term, giving

$$qx(1+q)^{x-1} = q\frac{d}{dq}(1+q)^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty q\frac{d}{dq}\binom{x}{k} q^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \binom{x}{k}q^k.$$

Dividing both sides by $(1+q)^{x}$ and setting $q=-p,$ $x=-r$ yields

$$\frac{p\,r}{1-p} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \binom{-r}{k} (-1)^k (1-p)^r p^k = \sum_{i=0}^\infty k\,\Pr(k\mid r, p).$$

That is the definition of the expectation, *QED.*